# Trying to create tweet using tweepy raises "AttributeError: _make_request"

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I'm trying to create a tweet with a bot using tweepy, but I keep getting errors (as shown below).

I'm using Python 3 and Twitter APIv2.

When running only the `api.verify_credentials`, the authentication does succeed.

**UPDATE**

I managed to run this code successfully:

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key="XXXX",
    consumer_secret="XXXX",
    access_token="XXXX",
    access_token_secret="XXXX"
)

filename=open('content.txt.txt')

f=filename.readlines()

filename.close()

for line in f:
 try:
  client.create_tweet(text=line)
  print(line)
 except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as err:
   print("err")
   
print("יא גאון מחשבים")
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i wrote what errors i get, but i will make it clear in the body of the question

Comment: This seems to have little to do with text files, is the error not the same if you use a fixed string instead, like `tweepy.Client.create_tweet(Self, text = "hello", user_auth=True)`?

Comment: Are you sure that you do not need to create an *instance* of `tweepy.Client` first, and *then* call its `create_tweet` method?

Comment: when changing to fixed I get these errors: Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 16, in <module>
    if api.verify_credentials() == False:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
line 2492, in verify_credentials
    return self.request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
line 269, in request
    raise Unauthorized(resp)
tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
89 - Invalid or expired token.

Comment: That's a different error from *before* `create_tweet` is even called. Here, `verify_credentials` failed.

Comment: update: when changing to fixed script i'm getting the same errors (edited the code in the question)

Answer (score 0):

`create_tweet` is an instance method of the `Client` (or more correct the `BaseClient`) class. calling it like a static method and passing `typing.Self` to it as the instance is nothing that could ever work (you could pass `api` as the instance and it would work, but Python can pass the `self` parameter implicitly when you use something like `api.create_tweet(...)`).

Some further reading on everything:

- [Python's instance, class and static methods demystified](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/#instance-methods)
- [`typing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)
- [docs for `tweepy.Client.create_tweet`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.create_tweet)

Comment: so should i just change 'tweepy.Client.create_tweet(Self, text = line, user_auth=True)' to api.create_tweet(Self, text = line, user_auth=True)? or removing the Self?

Comment: change it to `api.create_tweet(text=line, user_auth=True)` (notice the change to `api.create_tweet(...)` and the removal of `Self`)